# TS2339: TypeScript error for redux type bindings

Tags: typescript, redux

I am new to TypeScript and getting error `TS2339` when trying to create my typed redux reducer. The error says:

[image]

Is there something wrong that I am doing with the typescript pipe operator? Thanks!

**sampleActionTypes.ts:**

```
export interface Data {
  allIds?: number[];
  byId?: object;
}

interface IncrementCount {
  type: string;
}

interface ReceiveData {
  type: string;
  data: Data;
}

export type SampleActionTypes = ReceiveData | IncrementCount;
```

**sampleReducer.ts:**

```
export interface SampleState {
  count: number;
  data: Data;
}

const initialState = {
  count: 0,
  data: {},
};

const sample = (state = initialState, action: SampleActionTypes): SampleState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT_COUNT': {
      const newCount = state.count + 1;
      return {
        ...state,
        count: newCount,
      };
    }
    case 'RECEIVE_DATA':
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.data, // error is here
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default sample;
```

Comment: discriminated union documentation is what you're looking for because it gives you type-guards for free

Answer (score 2):

```
export type SampleActionTypes = ReceiveData | IncrementCount;
```

The `data` property doesn't exist on the `IncrementCount` type.

You can

a) type assert

```
(action as ReceiveData).data
```

b) "branded" types (I don't know if this is 100% the correct term) **edit**: the correct term is "discriminated union"

```
interface IncrementCount {
  type: 'INCREMENT_COUNT';
}

interface ReceiveData {
  type: 'RECEIVE_DATA';
  data: Data;
}
```

TS should be able to figure the rest out via duck-typing

c) type guards

```
function isReceiveDataAction(x: any): x is ReceiveData {
  return x.type === 'RECEIVE_DATA'
}

function isIncrementAction(x: any): x is IncrementData {
  ...
}

if (isIncrementAction(action)) {
  // action is IncrementData
} else if (isReceiveDataAction(action)) {
  // action is ReceieveData
}
```